# How to print addition value in smarty template?

Tags: variables, smarty, addition

I've following smarty code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
          {if $user_package_type_documents}
            {assign var=cnt value=0}        
            {foreach from=$user_package_type_documents item='my_package_type_documents'}
              {if $my_package_type_documents.pt_doc_file_iname != ""}
          <li class="list-group-item test-series-item-ul-my-doc">
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="">
              <div class="test-series-heading-doc">
                <span>{$cnt + 1})</span><span>{$my_package_type_documents.pt_doc_title}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="">
              <div class="vr-outter-div">
                <a href='my_documents.php?op=download&pt_doc_id={$my_package_type_documents.pt_doc_id}' title="Package Type Document" class="btn btn-default btn-sm vr-btn">DOWNLOAD</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
              {assign var=cnt value=$cnt+1}
            {/if}
          {/foreach}
          {if $cnt == 0}
          <li class="list-group-item test-series-item-ul-my-doc">
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="">
              <div class="test-series-heading-doc">
                <span></span><span>Document Not Available.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="">
              <div class="vr-outter-div">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          {/if} 
        {else}
          <li class="list-group-item test-series-item-ul-my-doc">
            <div class="col-xs-7" style="">
              <div class="test-series-heading-doc">
                <span></span><span>Document Not Available.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5" style="">
              <div class="vr-outter-div">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        {/if}
        </ul>
```

In above code I want to print the values from 1 till the values come. For it I wrote the code `{$cnt + 1}` but still it's printing the value from 0. How to print this from 1? Also the initialization shouldn't be changed i.e. it should initialize to zero as it is now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In smarty you can't have whitespace in addition operation, so `{$cnt + 1}` won't work but `{$cnt+1}` should (you even do that later on).

Anyway if I understand what're trying to accomplish here, I think you can do it differently. First when you're looping over `user_package_type_documents` variable you can define loop name , so you'll be able to reference [`iteration` number](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration). That way you'll have those orderly numbers in your document list. In case your array is empty you can either set a condition checking it's count or add [`foreachelse`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) clause that would replace that `{if $cnt == 0}`.